# How to Add Hours with Variable to a date time Variable

Tags: php, datetime

My server API returns a time variable as GMT time.
I first find the difference to the local time.
Then I want to add the hours, but I don't know how to include the variable of the difference:

```
$df = "G:i:s";  // Use a simple time format to find the difference
$tz = 'Europe/Berlin';
$tz_obj = new DateTimeZone($tz);
$today = new DateTime("now", $tz_obj);
$ts1 = $today->format($df); //Locale Time
$ts2 = gmdate($df); // Timestamp of current UTC time
$ts3 = $ts1-$ts2; // The difference are 2
```

This will work:

```
$newDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($menue_datum. ' + 2 hours'));
```

But how can i insert my Variable $ts3?

```
$newDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($menue_datum. ' + {$ts3} hours'));
```

Comment: just use `""` double quotes so that the variable inside `"+ {$ts3} hours"` would be evaluated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a simple solution:

```
$newDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($menue_datum. ' + ' . $ts3 . 'hours'));
```